# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8000000000000010)

Tags: ios, swift

I have an application which has a collection view full of videos and images. When you tap on one of them you segue to a full screen to view the media. When I tap a image It works as needed. But when I run my application and tap one of those videos I get the error shown bellow:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8000000000000010)

I get this here:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

*Is this possibly due to memory problems?*

**What is happening and how do i fix this?**

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217233/thread-1-exc-bad-access-code-1-address-0x30000008) but was unable to solve it.

I have found that the fail actually occurs when the bellow function is called.

```
func getAndShowMedia(post: Post) {
    if post.media[numberMedia].image != nil {//here is still works, I am assuming this line is the line which actualy fails
        print("imageooooo")//When setting break point here it will crash
        mediaView.image = nil
        mediaView.image = (post.media[numberMedia].image)!
    } else {
        mediaView.layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        let videoURL = post.media[numberMedia].videoURL
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        print("videooooooo")
        playerLayer.frame = mediaView.bounds
        mediaView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player.play()
    }
}
```

Here:

```
func loadOtherData() {        
    getAndShowMedia(post: selectedPost!)
}
```

Comment: We can't fix your code if we don't have your code.

Comment: @Alexander please check edits

Comment: Make sure your outlets are correctly wired to the storyboard.

Comment: Is `videoURL` nil?

Comment: How do you know mediaView.layer contains a sub layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your code and tell me where be crash.

I read your code and assume happening crash, i write be below point and check the debug mode.

1. `post.media[numberMedia].image` you check is not nil please there case use `if let` statement.
2. `post.media[numberMedia].videoURL` is geting in your model `URL` object that will happening crash.
3. `mediaView.layer.removeFromSuperlayer()` i don't understand this code you have `remove` layer but you add sublayer `mediaView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)` then remove sublayer. Check your sublayer is available then remove sublayer, not remove `mediaView` layer.

use this code remove layer.

```
mediaView.layer.sublayers?.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperlayer() })
```

I hope this code will be work.

Answer (score -1):

From the Breakpoint menu in Xcode, press the '+' button at the bottom left then add an exception breakpoint. This will show you exactly where your app is crashing and you'll be able to debug it properly.

You have a few forced unwraps there that may be nil, you should avoid that.