# React native won't run on device but does on simulator via xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native

When using Xcode, My app is building as expected but it is failing when it starts running with the following error:

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x800000002)`

The app doesn't crash, it continues running but it just pauses on the launch screen.

However, it works as expected when running on the simulator via xcode. Do you have any idea why it might be failing when running on a physical device?

I have tried cleaning the build folder but it did not do any good.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217233/thread-1-exc-bad-access-code-1-address-0x30000008 check this. it might be helpfull